# IsEnabled=false to Grid Layout does not work in Xamarin.Forms Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Setting IsEnabled false to a Grid layout does not work in Android.

```
gdvUser.IsEnabled = false;
```

I tried with the same code in iOS and it works. Is this a bug?

Why I want to disable the Grid is because I have Entry fields in it and setting IsEnabled false to them changes the Entry properties. It sets the textcolor to black in iOS and my entry field has a black background so the text is not visible. Where as this works well in android. I am searching for a solution where I can disable my entry fields without any renderers or extra code.